# NSSortDescriptor to sort by value of a struct

Tags: objective-c, struct, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array that contains an object with two objects inside. One of them has this struct as a property:

```
typedef struct Price {
    int base;
    int net;
    int sell;
} Price;
```

I need to sort by "base" but I cannot figure out how

The structure is this:

Array containing ObjectsA.

ObjectA has two properties: ObjB and ObjC.

ObjC has Price as property.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: NSSortDescriptor searches key paths.  For all the KVO mechanism knows, there's just an opaque blob of memory called Price as a property that you may be able to get, but member access is probably not going to happen.

Comment: But can I use a custom compare function?

Comment: The comparator is expecting objects, but that might be pretty cool to try and investigate... Hold on a second and I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new property on my ObjC with an overrided getter that returns base from the struct used in the other property of the same object. It works but I don't know if it's the best way to accomplish this.